# Joining multiple tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with currency exchange rates:

```
CREATE TABLE ExchangeRates 
(
    ID int IDENTITY,
    SellingCurrency nvarchar(20),
    BuyingCurrency nvarchar(20),
    Rate float,
    CONSTRAINT PK__ExchangeRates__ID  PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

For example, table contains this data:

```
INSERT INTO ExchangeRates 
VALUES ('USD', 'RUB', 1.2),
       ('RUB', 'EUR', 0.5),
       ('SEK', 'RUB', 1.3)
```

I need to write a query which should return an exchange rate of two currencies even if there is no row in table with this two currencies (using a chain of exchanges).

How can I do it?

Comment: A bit offtopic, but aren't your currencies always related to same base currency (RUB)? If yes, then you should always store exchange rates relative to base currency - and this way you can always find cross rate, using exactly two joins.

Comment: @marc_s I thought about joining table with itself on `SellingCurrency = BuyingCurrency` but the problem is count of this   JOINs is not constant.

Comment: @Arvo No, this is just an example, real situation can be different.

Comment: What will be the input to the query. Like have you specify the  from and to currencies which should return an exchange rate..

Comment: What if there are 3 combined exchanges that give you the result? I think what you need is more related to business logic than database logic.

Comment: Furthermore, are buying and selling rates the same?

Comment: @Andrew 
1) The problem is I don't know how many exchanges I should do.
2) Rates can be different.

Comment: Furthermore :), do rates depend on current date, time and whatnotelse? (I'm just thinking about our app - rates are always related to base currency and can be entered once for each day. We are using just base ECB rates, no different sell, buy, cash etc ones - sufficient for 'bookkeeping' app.)

Comment: @Arvo No :) Rated depend on nothing, they are just numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is an excellent fit for solutions from the [graph theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory) field (and graph databases like [Neo4j](http://neo4j.com/) for example), but modelling a graph in a relational database isn't that hard and implementing an path finding algorithm like BFS/DFS or Dijkstra (for shortest path) is doable too, and could be a viable solution given a small enough data set (which an exchange rate table would be), although given the iterative nature of those algorithms I'm not sure they would scale that well (but it should be easy enough to implement the algorithm in a CLR proc for better performance).

Anyway, I like graph theory and found this problem interesting and went looking for, and found, a t-sql  stored procedure implementation of [Dijkstras algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) (among several others) [here](http://hansolav.net/sql/graphs.html), and played around with adapting it to your data (with a slight, and unnecessary change to the table structure - I put the currencies in a separate table to not have to modify the procedure too much) and got it working (the code isn't that hard to understand if you are familiar with how [Dijkstras algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) works).

You can look at the implementation with examples in [this SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/3a722/1).

The result from the example runs (five separate executions) :

```
| STARTNODE | ID | NAME | DISTANCE | PATH  | NAMEPATH    |
|-----------|----|------|----------|-------|-------------|
|       USD |  2 |  RUB |      1.2 |  1,2  |  USD,RUB    |
|-----------|----|------|----------|-------|-------------|
|       USD |  3 |  EUR |      1.7 | 1,2,3 | USD,RUB,EUR |
|-----------|----|------|----------|-------|-------------|
|       RUB |  3 |  EUR |      0.5 |  2,3  |  RUB,EUR    |
|-----------|----|------|----------|-------|-------------|
|       SEK |  2 |  RUB |      1.3 |  4,2  |  SEK,RUB    |
|-----------|----|------|----------|-------|-------------|
|       SEK |  3 |  EUR |      1.8 | 4,2,3 | SEK,RUB,EUR |
```

The test data uses these id numbers for currencies:

```
1 = USD
2 = RUB
3 = EUR
4 = SEK
```

Credit to the [author of the original algorithm](http://hansolav.net/sql/graphs.html)

On a side note it worth considering that even though it's clearly possible to use a relational database in this way, it's probably not a good idea; there are much better solutions for this.

Answer (score 0):

When you are sure you can fix it in 2 levels, you could use someting like this:

---

```
select Rate 
from ExchangeRates 
where SellingCurrency = 'SEK'
  and BuyingCurrency = 'EUR'
UNION 
select er1.Rate*er2.Rate as Rate
from ExchangeRates er1
left join ExchangeRates er2 on er2.SellingCurrency = er1.BuyingCurrency
where er1.SellingCurrency = 'SEK'
  and er2.BuyingCurrency = 'EUR'
```

Comment: The problem is I'm not sure I can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if you know that 'USD'/ 'RUB'=1.2 and 'SEK'/'RUB'= 1.3

then you can calculate that ('USD','SEK',1.2/1.3)--->('USD','SEK',0.92)

so, if you need rate (between two currencies 'a','b') 

that does not exists in that table

then find two rows with common currency ('a'/'c',x) and ('b','c',y) 

and do the calculation like i do.

('a','b',x/y) 

i hope i was clear enough.
```

Comment: Usually people put code without formatting it. It's strange to see the opposite: text formatted as code. :P